# Vim (7.3.3 Windows 64bit): Add ^M to end of line if there is none (ff=unix)

Tags: windows, vim, vi, eol, end-of-line

I have some 100,000+ files with partially mangled data, mixed text+binary files (a single file of jpg image data with http headers), where some header fields have dos style ^M^J line termination, and some only unix style ^J. When vim opens a file like this, it treats it as unix format. So all header lines where there is no ^M, one needs to be added. But this has proven to be very tough.

`:1,11s/Cache-Control:.*\zs^M\{0,}$/^M/`

doesn't work, and i've tried all kinds of variations of that, even using \=printf("%s","^M") as substitution string. But the result is always a new empty line in the file.

The ONLY way i'm able to add a ^M by a command at all is by

`:exe "normal A\<c-q>\<c-m>\<Esc>"`

Ok so one way would be to first remove any existing ^M, and then add it by previous. But is there a more elegant, one command solution?

(So that there would be no more misunderstandings, here's a short example of such a file:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.2.3
(more lines...)
Cache-Control: public, max-age=214748
(more lines...)

ÿØÿá Exif  II*            ÿì
```

)

Edit/solution: regarding 100,000+ files, here's a version (regarding missing ^M only on cache-control lines) that only matches if ^M is missing (as not all files are mangled, this will save large amounts of time together with "update!"):

`:1,11s/^Cache-Control:.\{-}\zs\(^M*$\)\(^M\)\@<!/\^M/i`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to configure the program reading the files to be tolerant of either line ending style (only in the header section)?

Comment: In this case it's not possible/wouldn't help. I'm doing this because i need to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A single command might look like `:v/^M/s/$/\^M/`. This uses `<C-v><C-m>`, which is to say... it inserts a literal `^M` character that's escaped with a backslash.

Comment: It's the backslash before ^M that eluded me, didn't know it's necessary after using ^V^M already. Thanks so much. The rest should be easy now.